# executing the http requests in multiple if condition in test fragment based on condition in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anat3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRjh.png)

Please find the snapshot and then come to the description.

How to call the if condition in the fragment from the different module controllers. My requirement is when END module is called the if condition1 should execute and when called START module the if condition2 should execute.
I tried using user parameters, user-defined variables & JSR223 Listeners but nothing worked as the values are updating globally. Please help here

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve it using single Module Controller, there is no easy and obvious way to determine the calling Module Controller from the [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) so the most straightforward option would be calling `HTTP-Request-1` from `Start` and `HTTP-Request-2` from END

[image]

If you need to execute HTTP-Request-1 and 2 conditionally - put the Module Controller under the [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and specify condition there, not in the Test Fragment.

More information: [Using JMeter Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)

Comment: I know the other way but I want to achieve more reusability. In ReadyAPI/SOapui there are options to call the desired requests. Do we have some thing like this here?